# Querying for Unique Ancestors of models in Google App Engine DS

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Anyone have any clean ways to get a unique list of the ancestors of entities of a particular model?

Eg If there is a class A, and a class B(parent=A), can one find all the A's that currently have B's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up doing a one liner;

```
a_with_b = set([b.parent() for b in B.all(keys_only=True)]) #list comprehension
```

FYI, in python 3, you could do

```
a_with_b = {b.parent() for b in B.all(keys_only=True)} #set comprehension
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I can think of is to do a keys_only query on B's and store their parent keys.  If you have a lot of B's this will be a pain in the A. ;)

```
all_b = B.all(keys_only=True)

a_with_b = []

for b in all_b:
    parent = b.key().parent()

    if not parent:
        continue

    if parent not in a_with_b:
        a_with_b.append(parent)
```